# How to change an argument “const” to “non-const” when calling a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I've got a problem when the function is called by other functions.

My functions are so:

```
void *table_lookup(const table *t) {
    ...
    //Here I want to call my other function. 
    table_remove(t);
    ...
}

void table_remove(table *t) {
    ...
}
```

I got a warning when I compile it. The problem is that I cannot change the argument's type.

Comment: Why do you think you can remove stuff from a `const` table? Why would you need to remove stuff while looking up stuff?

Comment: Probably a typo, but `table t` is not the same as `table *t` in your `table_remove` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You must NOT cast away the `const` qualifier. Any attempt to thereafter modify the value that was qualified `const` invokes *Undefined Behavior*. See [C11 Standard - 6.7.3 Type qualifiers(p6)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6).

The `table_lookup` parameter is `const` qualified for a reason. It allows the compiler to optimize the use of `t`. If you cast away the `const` and attempt to modify `t` you are breaking your promise to the compiler that `t` won't be modified.

Instead, you should refactor your code so that the `remove()` function calls `table_lookup` inside it to obtain a pointer (presumably) to the node you wish to remove. Then remove the `node`. Don't try and add a `remove()` within `table_lookup`. Create a new function.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can directly cast it to remove the 'const' property.

```
void *table_lookup(const table *t)
//Here I want to call my other function. 
table_remove((table*)t)   // remove 'const' by directly casting.
...
return

void table_remove(table *t)
...
```

Comment: If you directly cast a `const table *t` as `(table *)t` and then modify `t` you are screwed (likely SegFault). It is bad practice leading to undefined behavior to attempt to cast away the `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* cast away the `const` qualifier: `table_remove((table *)t);` but you might run into problems if `table_remove` tries to modify the `table` structure, for example if it is stored in a read-only segment.

Therefore you **should not** do it. It is rather unexpected that a lookup function would modify the table anyway. If it does for good reasons, such as building a hash table or maintaining a cache, the argument should not be declared as `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes That’s right.  it was bad idea to cast away const qualifier. . I can’t add a new function either. ((table)*) gives problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-qual"
void *table_lookup(const table *t) {
    table_remove((table *)t);
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253997/5093308